# Writing Data To Access2010 from VB2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm trying to write data to an Access 2010 table from VB 2010. Here's the VB code:

```
        Dim cn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ssr2011f\be\ssrAnalysisTWEAK.ACCdb")
        cn.Open()
        Dim Str As String = "insert into BSP1 values(" & CInt(pcValue) & ",'" & (hsName) & ") "
        Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(Str, cn)
        Dim icount As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

I get the following error at the line "cn.Open()":

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

I also got this error using the Connection string "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\ssr2011f\be\ssrAnalysisTWEAK.ACCdb;". My Windows version is 7.0.

Why is the connection failing?

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: Is the missing quote a paste error ? `& ") "` should be `& "') "`

Comment: @HansUp Hence the comment, rather than answer. It saves time in the end.

Comment: @George Try these Connection Strings and see if they work: [Connection String - Access 2010](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2010/) You may have to double wack your directory as well, like `C:\\ssr2011f\\be...`

Answer (score 1):

I have seen errors like this before when using an Access database as a back end, while developing on a computer that is running a 64-bit operating system.

Try explicitly targeting the x86 platform in your Visual Studio project's compile options.

In the solution explorer, right click on your project and select **Properties**

Select the **Compile** tab

Click the **Advanced Compile Options** button

In the **Target CPU** dropdown, select "x86" (instead of "AnyCPU")

When I did this I was able to execute your code without errors (pointing it to my own access DB of course).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Or install the x64 ACE Drivers.  By default your system will have either the 32bit or the 64bit ACE drivers installed, dependent on the bitness of the version of MSOffice you installed.  You can only have one of these installed at a time if I remember correctly, so having x86 and x64 installed at the same time is out of the question.  Also, if you will be deploying your application to another PC which does not have MSOffice installed, you will need to install the ACE drivers and/or make sure the correct bitness of the ACE driver is present on that machine.